# Assign to a using variable before it is disposed

Tags: c#, .net

Can you assign to a variable instantiated in a using statement before it is disposed at the end. E.g.

```
using (TempObj temp = new TempObj())
{
    temp.doStuff(......);

    realObj = temp; // <-------- Is this line ok?
}
```

If not why can't you?

Edit: I mean what will happen to realObj in this situation

Comment: Of course you can. It'll just still be disposed. Why don't you try it?

Comment: Per the edit, I repeat: It'll still be disposed. Why don't you try it?

Comment: I wasn't specific enough in my question so I edited

Comment: _"what will happen"_ -> if `TempObj` is properly implemented, you'll get `ObjectDisposedException`s when trying to access a method that no longer has access to something it needs

Comment: Yes, sure. You can use.  The using statement calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way, and (when you use it as shown earlier) it also causes the object itself to go out of scope as soon as Dispose is called

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, but `realObj` will hold an instance of a disposed object.

Do not use variables created in `using()` outside the `using` block.